# File not found maple.sty

Tags: miktex, texmaker

[image: Error output]

I am using texmaker (editor) and MikTex. I have converted my maple document to latex but I have tried several times to follow the guides to how I can point MikTex to the file maple.sty but I get the same error. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

- Create somewhere (outside miktex) a folder structure

  ```
    localtexmf/tex/latex/maple/
  ```
- put `maple.sty` style inside the `maple` folder
- go to the miktex console, Settings, tab Directories
- click on the + and choose the `localtexmf` folder as a new root.

[image]

- if you later add more local files to this texmf root you should update the file name database:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is quite simple comparing to all we have to read in Maple Help to make it work in texmaker. Thank you very much!